# Meaningful error/failure messages in burn bootstrapper / wix

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.10

I am trying to give customized/meaningful error messages if there is any failures while installing using burn bootstrapper.

A short intro about the installer. I am using burn bootstrapper which has chain msipackages(3). MSI package has custom actions in c#. I am using localization wxl. Below is the failure section and see the highlighted **custommessage**.

```
<Page Name="Failure">
<Text Name="FailureHeader" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureHeader)</Text>
<Text Name="FailureInstallHeader" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureInstallHeader)</Text>
<Text Name="FailureUninstallHeader" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureUninstallHeader)</Text>
<Text Name="FailureRepairHeader" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureRepairHeader)</Text>
<Hypertext Name="FailureLogFileLink" X="11" Y="121" Width="-11" Height="42" FontId="3" TabStop="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.FailureHyperlinkLogText)</Hypertext>
<Hypertext Name="FailureMessageText" X="22" Y="163" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="3" TabStop="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes" ></Hypertext>
<Hypertext Name="CustomMessage" X="22" Y="163" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="3" TabStop="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes" >[CustomMessage]</Hypertext>
<Text Name="FailureRestartText" X="11" Y="-51" Width="400" Height="34" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.FailureRestartText)</Text>
<Button Name="FailureRestartButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.FailureRestartButton)</Button>
<Button Name="FailureCloseButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.FailureCloseButton)</Button>
```

I can access this custommessage as a burn variable and pass to the msi using msiproperty

```
 <Variable Name="CustomMessage" Value="Hi"/>
 <MsiProperty Name="CustomMessage" Value="[CustomMessage]"/>
```

Also I can access this customMessage in the custom action using session["CustomMessage"]

Question:When I change this session["CustomMessage"] from custom Action it is not getting reflected back to the burn variable and back to the CustomMessage in wxl? Can anyone help me on this.

from Custom Action

```
session["CustomMessage"]="Please enter valid details";
```

Comment: Using the "embedded Burn protocol" in Isaiah4110's answer is only necessary when running non-MSI packages.  Burn uses the MSI API's to get meaningful error messages.  I do not know enough about the specifics about how to get a message from a custom action all the way to the bootstrapper application (BA), but MsiProperty is one way to the MSI.  The BA would get this information from a callback through the IBootstrapperApplication interface from the engine.

Comment: I don't want to write a custom BA since the WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense is working just fine. If I go for Custom BA then is there anyway to resuse this?

Comment: @Amanto did you succeed in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

From this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15115564/1766402) by @RobMensching, there is a way to do it. But unfortunately you will have to dig through the code to implement it.

> "Your executable could implement the "embedded Burn protocol" to send
>   rich progress and error messages. It isn't at all documented so you'd
>   need to go through the Burn code to see the protocol, but it's there
>   and would get you exactly what you want. The "bundlerunner" .csproj in
>   the WiX source code might be helpful too."

And this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119540/communication-with-wix-burn-bootstrapper-using-embedded-pipe) talks about 2 different approaches for the communication with the WiX bootstrapper. Hope this will be something for you to start with.